# firestore document update data without id

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have snapshot of a firestore collection,

```
fireStoreInst.collection(widget.loggedInUser.uid)
             .doc('subjects')
             .collection(widget.deckName).snapshots()
```

and I want to update the data inside which according to Flatbutton click(hard/good/easy).
when user click any of these 3 buttons I want to update the respective data to true and other 2 to false.

[image]

As I don't know the docID, I tried,

1.

```
widget.snapshot.data.docs[widget.cardIndex].updateData({
          widget.hardness: true,
          widget.remove1: false,
          widget.remove2: false
        });
```

2. And for getting the DocumentID I tired,

```
docID: snapshot.data.docs[cardIndex].documentID
```

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('JWfsiG4VAQPpv3PNwP7E5dNbGEe2')
            .doc('subjects')
            .collection('Latest QA')
            .doc(widget.docID)
            .update({
          widget.hardness: true,
          widget.remove1: false,
          widget.remove2: false
        });
```

But all ended up in errors. most of them due to deprecated codes can anyone help me?

Comment: What error you are getting..!?

Comment: Class 'QueryDocumentSnapshot' has no instance getter 'documentID'.
Receiver: Instance of 'QueryDocumentSnapshot'
Tried calling: documentID

Comment: I don't know much about flutter.But as looking into error you have got it shows that you are trying to call method that is not available with the class .

Comment: I got this code from stackoverflow but recently a lot of codes were changed

Comment: Then please try with updated code

Comment: looking for it but didn't found

Answer (score 1):

**Problem solved:**

`docID: snapshot.data.docs[cardIndex].id`

instead of

`docID: snapshot.data.docs[cardIndex].documentID`

`documentID` deprecated